# Determining if a link exists w/ Cucumber/Capybara

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I want to verify that a link with a specific href exists on a page.  I am currently doing I should see "/some-link-here" but that seems to fail.  How can I make sure that link exists without having to do click + I should be on "/some-link-here" page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to add custom step

```
Then /^"([^\"]*)" should link to "([^\"]*)"(?: within "([^\"]*)")$/ do |link_text, 
page_name, container|
  with_scope(container) do
    URI.parse(page.find_link(link_text)['href']).path.should == path_to(page_name)
  end
end
```

You can use the step like `Then "User Login" should link to "the user_login page"`, user_login is the name of your route

Answer (score 0):

I used jatin's answer, but have a separate scoping step:

```
When /^(.*) within ([^:]+)$/ do |step, parent|
  with_scope(parent) { When step }
end

Then /^"([^\"]*)" should link to "([^\"]*)"$/ do |link_text, page_name|
  URI.parse(page.find_link(link_text)['href']).path.should == path_to(page_name)
end
```

Then I have this in my test:

```
step '"my foods" should link to "food_histories" within ".tabs"'
```

And this in my paths:

```
# note: lots not shown
def path_to(page_name)
  case page_name
  when /^food_histories$/
    food_histories_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done myself, quite simple but it does mean you are hardcoding your url which to be honest is not ideal as it makes your test very brittle. Especially if you are using 3rd party URL's!

But if you are using a url that you manage and are happy to maintain this test then go for it.

```
Then /^the link is "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
   page.should have_xpath("//a[@href='" + arg1 + "'][@target='_blank']")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I first landed here, when looking for a solution and thought I would give an updated answer. It depends what your capybara syntax is, but using the matcher [`has_link?`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_link%3F-instance_method) you could write for `href = /some-link-here` and `link_text "Click Me"`

`expect(page).to have_link("Click Me", href: '/some-link-here')`